# Add PHLivePhotoView to the storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

I'm trying to put a `PHLivePhotoView` into the `WelcomeVideoItemViewController` using Storyboard. For this purpose the view with a custom class is configured:
[image: Custom class (PHLivePhotoView)]

The scene hierarchy:
[image: Hierarchy of a ViewController]

The implementation of the custom View Controller:

```
class WelcomeVideoItemViewController: UIViewController, PHLivePhotoViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var livePhotoView: PHLivePhotoView!

    @IBOutlet weak var tipImageView: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var tipLabel: UILabel!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print(livePhotoView)
        // Optional(<UIView: 0x7fd161f200b0; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x60000134ac60>>)

        // Crash here
        livePhotoView.delegate = self
    }
}
```

So the problem is that the `livePhotoView` is initialized with a `UIView` instance, which leads to crash because the `UIView` has no `delegate` property. Ho can I make this custom class work?

*Xcode 10.2, iOS 12.2, Swift 4.2*

Comment: For a person, who downvoted the question and marked it for closing because of "Why this code isn't working": This question clearly indicates, that there is a bug within the SDK, and it has nothing to do with my code. The Storyboard doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a workaround for this. First, create a custom `PHLivePhotoView` subclass:

```
import PhotosUI

class LivePhotoView: PHLivePhotoView {
}
```

Then, drag a `View` to the storyboard and set the custom class for it:

[image: Custom Class]

Don't forget to check `Inherit Module From Target`.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just set class name as `PHLivePhotoView`

[image]

Comment: Reed the question carefully, I tried this option, as the first screenshot shows. And it didn't work.